# Add multiple filter in ElastAlert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastalert, elastalert2

We have 2 fields in the ElasticSearch

- api_status = 400 or 200 or 500
- api_url = /v1/myapi.com

In elastAlert how can I get the filter to fetch if all status=400 that are coming for all events with api_url within 10min are 5% of the total count?

Total count api_uri=/v1/myapi.com -> 1000 in 10 min

Total count api_status=400        -> 100 in 10 min

So 4xx is >5% of the total count

and the same trigger should happen through Elast Alert